# Unity 2019 Высота trrain (y) по координатам x,z

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу поднимать объект не через коллайдеры всякие а с помощью скрипта. Как мне получить высоту terrain под объектом (Y). Чтобы поднимать сам объект по Y на полученную высоту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет `terrain.SampleHeight`, он возвращает высоту террейна в точке и принимает на вход мировые координаты.

```
public class populate : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;

    void Start () {
        var terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var go = Instantiate (prefab);
            var x = Random.value*100;
            var z = Random.value*100;
            var y = terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x, 0, z));
            go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На основе скрипта написал скрипт для игрока вот

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class ScriptAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Terrain terrain;
    public float height = 0;


    void Start()
    {
       
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //var terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();

        float x = transform.localPosition.x;
        float z = transform.localPosition.z;
        var y = terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x, 0, z));
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y+ height, z);



    
    }
}

Comment: Если не трудно подскажите почему персонаж при движении влетает в гору а только потом стает на место, и при спуске с горы как будто падает? эффект инертности массы тела. но коллайдеров на нём нету.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка это надо смотреть, вечерком попробую

Comment: Спасибо Я думаю проблема в том что движение у меня в отдельном скрипте, Попробую см решить.